# Stream Ubuntu Microphone to Mac

Tags: microphone, mac

I have a mac without a microphone, however I wish to use Garageband with one. I have an Ubuntu 18.04 laptop which does have one, and I wonder if there's a way to stream the microphone to mac over my network.

Edit:
Software, not hardware please.

Answer (score 1):

Jack Network connection kit should be able to help with this.

Comment: Its https://jackaudio.org/downloads/ and it seems to have a Mac version. Please read https://jackaudio.org/faq/netjack.html to understand how this can work.